# The operator > is undefined for the argument type(s) Object, int

Tags: java, collections, linkedhashmap

I am writing a code to find first duplicate character in a string with following code

```
package collectionsExample;

import java.util.*;

class LinkedHashMap1
{
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String word = "Hare Krishna";
        char[] characters = word.toCharArray();

        // build HashMap with character and number of times they appear in String
        LinkedHashMap<Character, Integer> charMap = new LinkedHashMap<Character, Integer>();
        for (Character ch : characters) {
            if (charMap.containsKey(ch)) {
                charMap.put(ch, charMap.get(ch) + 1);
            } else {
                charMap.put(ch, 1);
            }
        }

        System.out.println(charMap);
        for(Map.Entry p : charMap.entrySet()){
            if(p.getValue() > 1){
                System.out.println(p.getKey());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I am getting error when I do p.getValue() > 1.
The error is The operator > is undefined for the argument type(s) Object, int
If p.getValue() returns int then greater than and less operator should work

Comment: The error message is very clear: p.getValue() returns an `Object` which obviously cannot be compared directly to an int.

Comment: It should be pointed out that all objects that inherit Collections, at least in my experience, default T or E to object if left unspecified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to parametrize your `Map.Entry`:

```
for(Map.Entry<Character, Integer> p : charMap.entrySet()){
```

... otherwise it is interpreted as a raw `Map.Entry`, which is equivalent to a `Map.Entry<Object, Object>`, hence the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
for(Map.Entry p : charMap.entrySet())
```

to

```
for(Map.Entry<Character,Integer> p : charMap.entrySet())
```

When you use a raw `Map.Entry`, the compiler doesn't know that the values of your entries are `Integer`s.

Answer (score 2):

If you use plain `Map.Entry` then as far as the compiler is concerned, the key and value fields are of the base type `Object`. If you use `Map.Entry<Character, Integer>` then the key and value will be a `Character` and an `Integer` respectively.